# i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException but i got value from textbox

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

What is the problem in my code?

```
orderIsbnDetails.setIsbn(request.getParameter("isbn"+ i).trim());
```

This line throws NullpointerException

Comment: Post your relevant `jsp` and `spring - controller` part.

Comment: The parameter wasn't present, obviously, or else `orderIsbnDetails` is null.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan 'Throughs' is no improvement over 'through' here.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("isbn"+ i)`is null.

`null.trim()` causes `NullPointerException`.